# Confused on algebraic step to derive a rule for partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I am trying to understand the partial fraction identity
$$\frac{5x+4}{(x^{2}+9)(x-1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} +\frac{Bx + C}{(x^{2}+9)}$$
I transformed it to be equal to
$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+3i} + \frac{C}{x-3i} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^{2}+9}$$
I changed
$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+3i} + \frac{C}{x-3i}$$
to be
$$A(x+3i)(x-3i) + B(x-1)(x-3i)+C(x-1)(x+3i)$$
How do I proceed from this step to make it look like
$$\frac{A}{x-1} +\frac{Bx + C}{x^{2}+9}?$$

Comment: your B's and C's aren't the same

Comment: I don't understand, aren't they suppose to have different denominator values?

Comment: $$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+3i} + \frac{C}{x-3i} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{(B+C)x-3i(B-C)}{x^{2}+9} $$

Comment: I understand the algebra now. how is the numerator equal to Bx + C if there is some imaginary number being subtracted?

Comment: You are assuming that $B$ and $C$ (in the complex version of the expression) are real. They will not be in this case. FYI, your original expression should be $$\frac{5x+4}{(x^2+9)(x-1)}$$ Those parentheses are important.;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+3i} + \frac{C}{x-3i} = \frac{   5x+2}{(x^2+9) (x-1)     }$$
$$ \implies A(x+3i)(x-3i) + B(x-1)(x-3i)+C(x-1)(x+3i)=5x+2$$
$$ \implies (A+B+C)x^2 + [ -B(1+3i) -C(1-3i)  ]  x+ +[ 9A+3i(B-C)] =5x+2$$

This is an identity in $x$ so we can equate coefficients of powers of $x$
we require: ::
$$A+B+C=0$$
$$  -B(1+3i) -C(1-3i)  =5  $$
$$9A+3i(B-C)=2$$

so
$$B+C=-A$$
$$  B+C = -3i(B-C) -5 \implies 3i(B-C) = A-5  $$
$$9A+A-5=2 \implies A=\frac{7}{10}$$
$$ B-C = \frac{1}{3i} \left(  -\frac{43}{10}  \right) =i  \left(  \frac{43}{30}  \right) $$
$$ B+C = -\frac{7}{10}  $$

$$  B=  -\frac{7}{20}  + i  \left(  \frac{43}{60}  \right) $$
$$  C=  -\frac{7}{20}  - i  \left(  \frac{43}{60}  \right) $$

Putting it all together and using the expression given in my comment :

$$\frac{   5x+2}{(x^2+9) (x-1) }   =\frac{\frac{7}{10}}{x-1} + \frac{-\frac{7}{20}  + i  \left(  \frac{43}{60}  \right) }{x+3i} + \frac{-\frac{7}{20}  - i  \left(  \frac{43}{60}  \right) }{x-3i} 
\\= \frac{\frac{7}{10}}{x-1} + \frac{-\frac{7}{10} x +   \left(  \frac{43}{10}  \right) }{x^2+9} $$